# Where is the ghost's grave?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I'm walking around the island with this annoying ghost following me. He asked me to take him to his house, which I found. Now, he's incessantly asking me to take home to his grave. I went to the graveyard and it doesn't seem to be there. **Where is the ghost's grave?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [zeldawiki.org](http://zeldawiki.org/Ghost_(Link's_Awakening)):

> The Ghost then asks Link to bring it to its grave, which is **located in the Koholint Prairie near the Cemetary**.

Koholint Prarie is west of the Graveyard and east of the Mysterious Woods, and the grave itself is towards the south west corner of Koholint Prarie.
[image: Location of Koholint Prarie and the grave]
This image from [zeldaelements.net](http://www.zeldaelements.net/games/c/links_awakening/maps) (edited by me) shows exactly where is it.